# Need a GridView for Qt without QML

Tags: qt

Is there a GridView implementation for native Qt (not for QML)? I need to read some data from model and put them into GridView.

GridView in QML support dynamic rows/columns, it's friendly to the users when resizing. Or, I have to implement it with `QWidget` and `QGridLayout`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience you have several possibilities:

- As you said, use QGridLayout to display your custom data
- QTableView works out of the box with Qt model classes, you can pretty much customize it easily to include widgets and other data as you wish.
- Use QGraphicsView/QGraphicsScene to draw a grid, basically QML is built on top of QGraphicsView... it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 2):

[QTableView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtableview.html#details) or [QTableWidget](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtablewidget.html#details) should be the starting points.

Answer (score 0):

There is commercial data grid for Qt/C++ here http://www.devmachines.com/qtitandatagrid-overview.html We use it without any issues.

Comment: Good library, but not suitable for any FOSS projects.